# De-normalize a dataframe by extracting some key/value pair from a dict column while keeping others as new records

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have an extremely complex pandas dataframe which has 4 columns as:
[id, email id, phone, conversation] but the conversation column here is a dict but is stored as a string like:

```
   id | email     | phoneNo | conversation
-------------------------------------------------
0  10 | abc@g.com |   123   | {"subject": "abc", "ts": "2021:10:06", "metadata": {"key: value"}, "content": "[email body]", "conversation_id": "100A"
1  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   | {"subject": "xyz", "ts": "2021:10:08", "metadata": {"key: value"}, "to" : "999", "from" : "789", "conversation_id": "101B"
```

present data types:

```
id[0] > int
email[0] > str
ph[0] > str
conversation[0] > str
```

The conversation holds the details of customer interaction and it can be through sms text, emails or even telephonic conversation.

Therefore, problem is that metadata can have many key value pairs (or even nested lists/dicts) inside it and that is not strict to each record. For example case one may have 5 such key value pairs inside it (subject, ts, metadata, content, conversation_id) while second one may have 3 (subject, ts, metadata, to, from, status, conversation_id, etc.), and so on. What is sure is that conversation id will be there no matter what mode of communication it is and will be unique for each.

So I want to de-normalize this JSON in a way that the key value pairs comes as this:

```
   id | email     | phoneNo | conversation_id |   keys      |   values
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  10 | abc@g.com |   123   |     100A        |   subject   |    abc
1  10 | abc@g.com |   123   |     100A        |   ts        | 2021:10:06
2  10 | abc@g.com |   123   |     100A        |   metadata  | {"key: value"}
3  10 | abc@g.com |   123   |     100A        |   content   | [email body]
4  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   |     101B        |   subject   |    xyz
5  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   |     101B        |   ts        | 2021:10:08
6  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   |     101B        |   metadata  | {"key: value"}
7  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   |     101B        |   to        |     999
8  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   |     101B        |   from      |     789
```

expected data types:

```
id[0] > int
email[0] > str
ph[0] > str
conversation_id[0] > str
keys[0] > str
values[0] > str
```

I am struggling to first convert the conversation column from str to dict and then how do I just keep the ones I need as a separate column (conversation_id) and rest can come in key/value columns respectively.

I have been asked to think of a possible function that can take this input dataframe and return values like the second dataframe.

The reason why we decided to keep the key/value pair is because of the uncertainty in converting each key value pair into column as it may not be fixed. That way I can fix the number of columns to 6 and create a schema in the database accordingly to load it.

However, if that is possible to create "n" number of columns irrespective of whether the other record have that key/value pair or not by putting NULL it will be great too, but then I am not sure if that can be converted into a table schema later on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert str representation of `dict` to an actual `dict`, then proceed like following:

```
from ast import literal_eval

conversations = df.pop('conversation').apply(literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)
df['conversation_id'] = conversations.pop('conversation_id')
stacked_conversation = ( conversations.stack().reset_index(level=1)
                         .set_axis(['keys', 'values'], axis=1) )
result = df.join(stacked_conversation).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   id      email  phoneNo conversation_id      keys        values
0  10  abc@g.com      123            100A   subject           abc
1  10  abc@g.com      123            100A        ts    2021:10:06
2  10  abc@g.com      123            100A  metadata  {key: value}
3  10  abc@g.com      123            100A   content  [email body]
4  12  xyz@g.com      789            101B   subject           xyz
5  12  xyz@g.com      789            101B        ts    2021:10:08
6  12  xyz@g.com      789            101B  metadata  {key: value}
7  12  xyz@g.com      789            101B        to           999
8  12  xyz@g.com      789            101B      from           789
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is really helpful. I have already used "literal_eval" to convert the str looking dict to dict but because of the content of the json which has email body and can have symbols and what not, it continues to throw error. I tried a lot to fix it but I get this error:
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f99e8fa5670>

Comment: If I exclude ".apply(literal_eval)" then it throws me the error: key error: 'conversation_id'. Any idea how can I proceed in such a scenario?

Comment: Can you apply `json.loads` instead of literal_eval?